# If Loop has odd number of posts on last page Custom style for last post in it

Tags: loop, pages, post-class

My loop displays posts in two columns using this php

```
<?php
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 $count++;
?>
    <?php  if ($count == 1) : ?>
    <div class="home-ci-row">

    <div style="padding: 0px;" class="main-column-item-wrap">
    CONTENT OF POST : Title, Thumbnail, Excerpt... etc
    </div>

    <div class="home-ci-gap"></div><!-- /* the gap */ -->

    <?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>    

   <div style="padding: 0px;" class="main-column-item-wrap">
   CONTENT OF POST : Title, Thumbnail, Excerpt... etc
   </div> <!-- main-column-item-wrap -->


</div><!-- /* home-ci-row*/ -->

<?php $count = 0; ?>

      <?php else : ?>
  WHEN THERE IS NO POSTS
<?php endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

You can see that the div '' opens in the first count & closes in the second one.

so when my loop has an even number of posts works great, but with odd number it doesn't close the div

so My idea is this: 
If loop has even number
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu4Ua.png

If loop has odd number of posts 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjqzZ.png

I hope my question is clear,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this much easier. As you are making a layout that can be achieved by floats, there is no need to declare a Row every second time.

In my Code example I just youse the `$count` to determine the Class of the HTML-Element. In combination with the total Number of Posts displayed.

If the total number of posts `$wp_query->post_count` is reached by the `$count` AND the total number is odd, I give the Element the Class `fullwidth`. In the same way, I determine if it is the first or the second (see the IF-Statement).

All I need to do afterwards is output the corresponding Class for each HTML-Element in the Loop. Besides the Class, no Element is diffferent from each other.

I use the `Modulo` Operator in PHP ( `%` ) to determine odd/even. It delivers `1` if I use `$count % 2` and `$count` is odd. If you are not sure about this operator, read about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

So your code could look like this:

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if ( ++$count == $wp_query->post_count && ( $wp_query->post_count % 2 ) == 1 ) {
            // if final count is reached AND final count is odd
            // full width item
            $postclass = "fullwidth";
            $opentag = '';
            $closingtag = '</div>';
        } else if ( ( $count % 2 ) == 1 ) {
            // if $count is odd it is the first item in a 'row'
            $postclass = "halfwidth first";
            $opentag = '<div class="home-ci-row">';
            $closingtag = '';
        } else {
            // second item in a row
            $postclass = "halfwidth second";
            $opentag = '';
            $closingtag = '</div>';
        }
?>
    <?php echo $opentag; ?>
    <div class="main-column-item-wrap <?php echo $postclass; ?>">
    CONTENT OF POST : Title, Thumbnail, Excerpt... etc
    </div><!-- main-column-item-wrap -->
    <?php echo $closingtag; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: This would work for me I will use it, but How can I echo this `<div class="home-ci-row">` at the begging of the loop then comes `<div class="main-column-item-wrap <?php echo $postclass; ?>">` twice then close the loop with `</div><!-- /* home-ci-row*/ -->`

Comment: why do you need the `<div class="home-ci-row">`? you would be mucch more flexible if you do not put this div around the items.

Comment: I need it if possible

Comment: see updated version. still, it would be better if you created the rows by css instead of a div.