# Display an image if odd number of posts in grid

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

I want to loop my posts into a 2 column grid, but if there is an odd number of posts, there is an empty space on the even side of the grid.

How could I get an image to appear in this empty space *only* if there are an odd number of posts? So it would be:

```
Post 1 | Post 2

Post 3 | img
```

I tried using [the code here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/if-loop-has-odd-number-of-posts-on-last-page-custom-style-for-last-post-in-it), but not sure how to apply the `Modulo` Operator because the image should appear after the loop, no?

If my code is super basic like:

```
<div class="small-12 large-6 columns end">
  <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    Post title, thumbnail, excerpt, etc
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The common mistake people make in this situation is they start to introduce bunch of custom counters to keep track of state.

Really `WP_Query` just *has those* already. In your case that would be global `$wp_query` and `$wp_query->post_count` and `$wp_query->current_post`. That should be quite enough to figure out even/odd overall and current iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in current_post you can easily separate the odd and even post.

```
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'    => 4,
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            if( $loop->have_posts() ):
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    if ( $loop->current_post % 2 == 0 ):
                        // Even
                        the_title();
                    else:
                        // Odd
                        the_title();
                    endif;

                endwhile;
            endif;
```